# Service status not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, service, pid

I have the following code for a service that I'm trying to have automatically start on boot.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

RETVAL=0

prog='foo'
exec="/usr/sbin/$prog"
pidfile="/var/run/$prog.pid"
lock_file="/var/lock/subsys/$prog"
logfile="/var/log/$prog"

if [ -f /etc/default/foo ]; then
  . /etc/default/foo
fi

if [ -z $QUEUE_TYPE ]; then
  echo 'ENV variable QUEUE_TYPE has not been set, please set it in /etc/default/foo'
  exit 1
fi

get_pid() {
  cat "$pidfile"
}

is_running() {
  [ -f "$pidfile" ] && ps `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting Consul daemon: "
    #
    daemon --pidfile $pidfile --check foo --user my-user "my app stuff here"
    echo
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n 'Stopping Consul daemon: '
    killproc foo
    echo
    ;;
  status)
    status $pidfile
    RETVAL=$?
    #status -p $pidfile -l $prog
    #[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && RETVAL=$?
    #RETVAL=$?
    #if is_running; then
    #  echo 'Running'
    #else
    #  echo 'Not Running'
    #fi
    #status foo
    #RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    RETVAL=$?
    ;;
  *)
    echo 'Usage: foo {start|stop|status|restart}'
    exit 1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

When I run `sudo service foo status` it says that it hasn't been started which is correct. After running `sudo service foo start` and then running the `status` command, it tells me that the service hasn't been started. I'm not sure what is causing this to happen. I looked at the configurations for other `init.d` scripts to see how they were handling this and tried to follow their lead. Is there something obvious here that I'm doing wrong or something else that I may be unaware of that's causing this problem?

Comment: Did you check that your service is running after `sudo service foo start` ?
For example with : `ps -ax | grep [f]oo` ?
It may have failed with an error. 
Have you checked system logs? (`tail -f /var/log/messages`  or  `journalctl -f`)